# Ubuntu Screen goes black after boot using Dedicated GPU

Tags: boot, ati, graphics, uefi

After installing a fresh copy of Ubuntu (14.04 LTS) I am not able to see anything after boot. Once Ubuntu boots, There is no HDD Activity and the Display remains black with no image on the screen(Example: Using HDMI on GPU to tv says no signal).

I only can get a signal using Intel Integrated graphics as well as seeing the login screen
and desktop, but upon using Dedicated GPU there is nothing to do. Even pressing the power button does nothing causing me to force power off the desktop.

I cannot open terminal(Ctrl+ALT+F1-F7), Basically it's dead when using the GPU.

All hardware works fine and fully tested, I get the same problem on another system as well
Hardware information is below.

CPU: Intel Core i3 3240
GPU: MSI R7 260 OC Edition 1GB(brand new and works on windows and other LinuxOS)
Memory: 4GB
OS: Ubuntu 14.04LTS(installed under UEFI)
Motherboard: ECS H61H2(UEFI)

my reason for the GPU is to use steam and game on linux.

Any help would be appreciated.

edit

I do see the Ubuntu bootup screen(logo with the dots)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had this problem as well and can possibly be related to the kernel. You can either try booting up on older kernel with GRUB and seeing if another older kernel boots correctly. If it does, you might need to report a bug report on http://launchpad.net/