# how to get Ubuntu 14.10 to boot up

Tags: boot, reboot

down loaded Ubuntu 14.10 for AMD 64. New pc. burnt iso image to dvd. installed on clean drive ok. Passwords worked fine. auto downloaded updates. installed ok. Restart did not work.my machine shut down to black screen then beeped to boot. the screen went lite reddish then black. My Panasonic 58 inch monitor indicated loss of signal. then indicated a signal was back. the screen is still black. pc is running but   unresponsive. Reinstalled several times. No luck. Tried a number of things suggested from the internet. no luck.

Tried loading 14.04(clean iso from the net)and formatted harddrive After the first update it was working but the second update changed my password and user names and loaded my laptops everything (Firefox/Thunderbird/add ons etc. then it would not accept my password. ( would this be the problem with my 14.10 installation?

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop and I like it. I want Ubuntu on my desktop that i'm using as multi-media in my living room.

Hope you can help

Bob

Comment: What were the "number of things suggested from the internet. no luck" that you tried? And this is about your desktop, with it's only monitor a 58" big screen tv? Did you try plugging in a regular monitor to a different video port when it boots to a black screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be due to a kernel update, but the kernel doesn't work with your machine. Please see this, although it relates to a GPU driver issue, the answer might assist with your problem: [Ubuntu Screen goes black after boot using Dedicated GPU](https://askubuntu.com/questions/571442/ubuntu-screen-goes-black-after-boot-using-dedicated-gpu/571448#571448)

Answer (score 1):

I cleaned the drive and installed 14.04. it booted up from install and it ran like a clock. It rebooted ok. checked the updates and only ran the security updates. rebooted ok. serfed the net. Videos music etc were great. reboot ok. did the full update. I got to the Ubuntu screen then black screen and nothing. unplug tv plug in monitor (15 pin connector) and there was the desktop prompting for my password
I entered it and it works ok.

If there is a fix i think I'm lucky and greatful. If no fix, and i can help making the OS better by giving you more hardware info. i'd be glad to.

Thanks again
Bob

Comment: Bob, that would be great, you can file a bug report with exact steps as mentioned above with `ubuntu-bug plymouth`. This is best guest as it might also be a problem with lightdm, however I'm sure someone will re-assign to the correct package after verifying.

Answer (score 0):

I"ll dig up a monitor and let you know. I spent a lot of time with the 14.04 version and what was happening there the downloads making changes to passwords and user names and adding information that I thought was only on my laptop so by the time i finely got the updates to work with my password on ver 14.10 only to see nada  i was about to give up.

Thought it might be the tv (works with windows). Hop there's a fix if it is.
I'll get back about the monitor
Thanks for the response
Bob